# How to Upload text, pdf, doc, zip file via PHP file upload to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I just implemented an image upload to MySQL via PHP. But i want to upload text, pdf, doc, zip file to MySQL. This is my code. How to change it ?

```
// uploadAction.php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1989") 

or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("uploadfile") or die(mysql_error());


$sql_id = "SELECT (MAX(id)+1) as \"result\" FROM save";

$rs_id = mysql_query($sql_id);

$row_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_id);

$id = $row_id['result'];

if($id == null)

$id = 1;    

$newName = '';  

$file = $_FILES['photo']['name'];

if ((($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/gif")||

($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")||

($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["photo"]["size"] < 200000))
{

if ($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0)

    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"] . "<br />";

  else{  

      $newName = "$id.".basename($_FILES["photo"]["type"]);

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "images/" . $newName);

      }

} 

else

  {

  echo "Invalid file";

  }

$queryUser = "INSERT INTO save VALUES(NULL, \"$newName\")";

$insert = mysql_query($queryUser);

if(!$insert){

    echo mysql_error().'Upload Fail';

  }else {

    echo "<script>alert('Upload Sccessful');";

    echo 'window.location="index.php";</script>';
}
```

Database SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `save` (

  `id` int(255) NOT NULL auto_increment,

  `photo` varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)

)
```

Comment: If you precede any line of code with four spaces, it will indent (see help on 'Markdown' syntax). A carriage return between every line makes for less readability too - would you edit? `:)`

Comment: Protip: When pasting code, highlight it and select `{}` from the toolbar (or press `Ctrl`+`k`).

Comment: Sorry about that. because i am a new user. haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/gif" ||
$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" ||   
$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg" || 
$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "application/zip" || 
$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "application/pdf" || 
$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "application/msword" || 
$_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
```

You can look at the different MIME-types here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Comment: Thanks your answer. But the msword and zip can't upload to MySQL.